# Card not being centred in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to center a group of cards but I cannot manage to do it. The cards are in a container and even with justify content center I cannot center them. Is there any solution? Example of my code is like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-lg-3 mt-4">
                    <div class="card text-center mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" />
                        </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an image showing that it is not centered.
[image]

Comment: Put the class `justify-content-center` on the `row` element, not its parent. Right now, you “centered” the row, which is always _full_ width to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the "`justify-content-center`" class to the element containing the "`row`" class.

**eg.**

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">...</div>
```

**snippet**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mx-lg-3 mt-4">
                    <div class="card text-center mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <img alt="Card image cap" class="card-img-top embed-responsive-item" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/800x600" />
                        </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```